# Angular2 RC5 TestBed - Use Location parameter injected into constructor

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am converting my Angular2 unit tests to the new syntax after upgrading to RC5.  I have a test that uses a value (Location) that is injected into the constructor of the component under test, and I cannot figure out how to do this with the new TestBed class.

The component under test

```
export class RSUAppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private _location: Location, private _appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) {
        _appSettingsService.DeleteAppSettings();
    }

    // To maintain proper nav item highlighting
    public IndicateSelected(linkRoute: string) {
        let path = this._location.path().toLowerCase();
        if (path.length == 0 && linkRoute.toLowerCase() == 'dashboard') {
            return "mdl-navigation__link mdl-navigation__link--current";
        } else {
            if (this._location.path().toLowerCase().includes(linkRoute.toLowerCase())) {
                return "mdl-navigation__link mdl-navigation__link--current";
            } else {
                return "mdl-navigation__link";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The test that worked pre-RC5

```
let testAppComponent: RSUAppComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
        AppSettingsService,
        // injected into the constructor of RSUViewer
        provide(Location, { useClass: SpyLocation })])
});

it('#IndicateSelected should return the selected styling for the selected menu item',
    async(inject([TestComponentBuilder, Location], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder, testLocation: SpyLocation) => {
        return tcb
            .overrideTemplate(RSUAppComponent, `
                    <nav class="mdl-navigation">                           
                    </nav>
            `)
            .overrideDirective(RSUAppComponent, RSUHomeComponent, EmptyComponent)
            .overrideDirective(RSUAppComponent, RSUNotiesComponent, EmptyComponent)
            .createAsync(RSUAppComponent)
            .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<RSUAppComponent>) => {
                let selectedOutput: string;
                fixture.detectChanges();
                testAppComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

                // initial navigation by app - user has not selected any menu link
                selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Dashboard');
                expect(selectedOutput).toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
                selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Noties');
                expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
                selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Users');
                expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');

                // user has selected the Users link
                testLocation.go('/users');
                selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Dashboard');
                expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
                selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Noties');
                expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
                selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Users');
                expect(selectedOutput).toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
            });
    }))
);
```

This is how I've attempted to rewrite the test.  The issue is that I don't know how to get the test to use the testLocation parameter so that it can switch the location.  In pre-RC5 it was injected into the test along with the TestComponentBuilder, but now we are not injecting our test component into the test.

```
let testAppComponent: RSUAppComponent;
let testLocation: SpyLocation;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [RSUAppComponent],
        providers: [
            AppSettingsService,
            // injected into the constructor of RSUViewer
            {provide: Location,  useClass: SpyLocation }
        ]
    })
});

it('#IndicateSelected should return the selected styling for the selected menu item',
    async(() => {
        TestBed.overrideComponent(RSUAppComponent, {
            set: {
                template: `
                    <nav class="mdl-navigation">                           
                    </nav>
            `

            }
        })
            .overrideDirective(RSUHomeComponent, EmptyComponent)
            .overrideDirective(RSUNotiesComponent, EmptyComponent);

        TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
            const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RSUAppComponent);
            let selectedOutput: string;
            fixture.detectChanges();
            testAppComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

            // initial navigation by app - user has not selected any menu link
            selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Dashboard');
            expect(selectedOutput).toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
            selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Noties');
            expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
            selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Users');
            expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');

            // user has selected the Users link
            testLocation.go('/users');
            selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Dashboard');
            expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
            selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Noties');
            expect(selectedOutput).not.toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
            selectedOutput = testAppComponent.IndicateSelected('Users');
            expect(selectedOutput).toMatch('mdl-navigation__link--current');
        });


    }));
```

Comment: I spent some time looking at the API documentation for inject and async, tried something like inject(async...) and the test gave an error that the component was not compiled, and googling gave me this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10943.  I changed my test as in the issue and used the work around, and it passed - correct syntax is

Comment: it('#IndicateSelected should return the selected styling for the selected menu item',
        async(inject([Location], (testLocation) => {
            const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RSUAppComponent);
            let selectedOutput: string;...